# I am getting The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.
CreateEvent @ Code.gs:26

and i couldnt find the root cause for it. Im new here and would appreciate if someone could point out my mistake. Thanks!

```
function CreateEvent() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_9a1e4a32dab9bdfe572d8e7c07f8fcb9a95694354df6939d58df5dc01187894c@group.calendar.google.com");
var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
var count = spreadsheet.getRange("A8:F"+lr+"").getValues();
var calsend = "CALSENT";
var row = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {
          var shift = count[x];
      
      var summary = shift[0];
      var startTime = shift[1];
      var endTime = shift[2];
      var guests = shift[3];
      var description = shift[4];
      var location = shift[5]; 
  
      var event = {
          'location': location,
          'description': description,
          'guests':guests +',',
          'sendInvites': 'True',
      }

eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event).addEmailReminder(120).addPopupReminder(120)


  row.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[7]) return;
    if(event = true)
    spreadsheet.getRange(index + 1, 7).setValue(calsend);
     
})

}
}
```

i tried to move to the bottom

```
eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event).addEmailReminder(120).addPopupReminder(120)
```

but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object)), the method you're trying to use expects proper `Date` object for start time and end time, I think you're passing strings instead.

Note that even if they look like dates, or are formatted like dates, in the cells of the sheet, Apps Script most likely see those as strings

```
var startTime = shift[1];
var endTime = shift[2];
```

You can confirm this by printing `typeof(startTime)` for example.